# Хочу сделать фильтр мата для телеграм бота, но появляется эта ошибка json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, filter

Есть отдельный json файл с матами,
Записал все маты вроде правильно,
Весь код думаю не стоит скидывать

Это код с общей части:

'''python

```
@dp.message_handler()

async def echo_send(message : types.Message):
    if {i.lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for i in 
message.text.split(' ') }\
        .intersection(set(json.load(open('cenz.json')))) != set():
            await message.reply('Маты запрещены')
            await message.delete()
```

а это импорт:

```
import json

ar = []

with open('cenz.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as r:
    for i in r:
        n = i.lower().split('\n')[1]
        if n != '':
            ar.append(n)

with open("cenz.json", 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as e:
   json.dump(ar,e)
```

Вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Судя по ошибке у вас проблема с файлом cenz.json, вы уверены что он в формате JSON? И файл не пустой?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

ar = []

with open('cenz.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as r:
    for i in r:
        n = i.lower().split('\n')[0]
        if n != '':
            ar.append(n)

with open("cenz.json", 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as e:
   json.dump(ar,e)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрались?
Скорее всего блокнот с матами который вы использует содержит другую кодировку. А у вас прописано utf-8. В данном случае стоит вписать нужную кодировку.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ошибка связана не с кодировкой, а с "битым" json в файле.